# Proving $\int_{(1,\infty)} f(s) \, ds < \infty$ by proving the divergence of a certain integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, reference-request, integral-inequality

Let $f: (1,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ be a continuous function which is bounded away from $0$ on compact sets. I'm looking for a statement of the following form:

> If $g$ is a function satisfying *******, then $$\int_{(1,\infty)} \frac{1}{f(s)} g(s) \, ds = \infty \tag{1}$$ implies $$\int_{(1,\infty)} f(s) \, ds < \infty. \tag{2}$$

From my point of view the most natural choice would be $g(s) = 1/s^{2+\epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon>0$; if

$$\int_{(1,\infty)} \frac{1}{f(s) s^{1+\epsilon/2}} \frac{1}{s^{1+\epsilon/2}} \, ds = \infty \tag{3}$$

then it is to be expected that $\frac{1}{f(s) s^{1+\epsilon/2}}$ cannot be too close to $0$ for large $s$ (otherwise the integral $(3)$ would be finite). If $f$ is monotone, then this is pretty straight-forward, but I would like to avoid this assumption. Any references or ideas?

Comment: Very confusing. Seems like you fixed $f.$ But then if $g$ does something or other, you want want $(1)$ to imply $(2)$ for all $f$?

Comment: @zhw. well, yeah, that's what I was looking for. (However, $g(s) = g(f(s))$ would be fine as well.)

Comment: If you fix $f\equiv 1$ then how could $s^{2 + \epsilon}$ work?

Comment: @zhw. Sorry there was a typo in there (which I fixed some minutes ago); it was supposed to read $g(s) = \color{red}{1/}s^{2+\epsilon}$.

Comment: For the monotone case, can't you take $f(s) = 1/[(s+1)\ln (s+1)]$ as a counterexample?

Comment: @zhw. Counterexample for what? If you define $f$ this way and choose $g(s) := 1/s^{2+\epsilon}$, then $(1)$ does not hold... or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, that was silly error. See my answer below for  a hopefully correct counterexample.

Comment: I realized that it actually does not even work for monotone functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample for the choice $1/s^{2+\epsilon}$: Let $g(s) = s^{-3}.$ We can find $f$ such that $f(s) = 1/n^3$ on the interval $[n,n+1/3], n = 2,3,\dots,$ and $f=1$ on $[n+1/2,n+2/3], n = 2,3,\dots $  You'll have $(1)$ holding because of what's happening on the first set of intervals, yet $\int_1^\infty f = \infty$ because of what's happening on the second set of intervals.

Comment: Yeah, that's true... and similar counterexamples can be constructed for any (reasonable) function gg. Well, that's a pity. However, I'm still wondering whether such an implication holds under somewhat stronger assumptions on $f$ (e.g. uniform continuity or $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x)=0$ or...).

Comment: ... but after some further thought, I think that it is possible to construct counterexamples also under these additional assumptions on $f$.